# Solution of $x'=Ax$ is not what it is supposed to be

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider a system of ODEs $x'=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
 -1&0 
\end{bmatrix}x$.

Wolfram Alpha says that the solution is $x(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos t &\sin t \\ 
 -\sin t& \cos t 
\end{bmatrix}x_0$. However, I can't get the same solution and I can't understand what my error is.

The method that I use is as follows.

(1) Find the eigenvalues: $\lambda =\pm i$.

(2) Find the vectors for $P$  from the eigenvectors of $A$, so $P=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\ 
 0&2 
\end{bmatrix}$, $P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\ 
 0&1/2 
\end{bmatrix}$.

(3) Thus $e^{At}=P\begin{bmatrix}
\cos t & -\sin t \\ 
 \sin t&\cos t 
\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos t & \frac{1}{2} \sin t \\ 
-2 \sin t&\cos t 
\end{bmatrix}$, which is not the answer that Wolfram Alpha gives.

Some advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Your eigenvectors are wrong: they shouldn't be real.

Comment: Hint: \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
 -1&0 
\end{bmatrix} is another way to state the imaginary unit. So basically you solve $x' =ix$.

Comment: @GyroGearloose: Sorry, I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: Square the matrix and you will see!

Comment: @Ian: I should've been more precise to have said that we are not using the actual eigenvectors in this case, but "extract" vectors for $P$ from the eigenvectors for $A$.

Comment: @GyroGearloose: I squared it and got $-I$. But how does this help?

Comment: Yes, just as $i^2=-1$. Let*s call the matrix $G$ in honer of Gauss and so it doesn't collide with $I$ for identity. You can map any $a+ib$ to $aI+bG$ and back.

Comment: If you want to solve in linear algebra way, you need to get correct eigenvectors in term of complex number. Some book short-cuts it complex part and list steps to follow in real numbers. It is hard to know which way you are following. I would prefer to do it by finding correct eigenvectors in compex number, solve it in the frame of linear algebra.

Comment: @runaround agreed, $x'=ix$ is the *easy* way, computing eigenvectors is the *better* (more general) way.

Comment: @runaround, oh I see, I wasn't finding the eigenvectors of the correct matrix, really need to get some sleep.

Comment: @GyroGearloose: If we solve $x'=ix$ then we get $x(t) = x_0 e^{it}$. We can expand it by the Gauss' identity, but we'll get a one-dimensional solution. Can you please clarify this for me? In my understanding, for $x(t) = e^{Gt}$, we're getting a simple Jordan block matrix without the need to check for eigenvalues or eigenvectors of $A$. Moreover, I think you meant the analogy between $x'=ix$ and $x' = Gx$.

Comment: Simply map the real part onto $I$ and the imaginary part onto $G$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't exactly understand what you mean. The real and imaginary parts of what?

Comment: @sequence Since you know that the solution to $x'=ix$ is $x_0 e^{it}$, you can read off the solution to your system as $(Re((x_1+ix_2)e^{it}),Im((x_1+ix_2) e^{it}))$, where $x(0)=(x_1,x_2)$.